# Random characters show up after string split

Tags: c#, string

I have a problem and seems I can't find any topic that discuss about this or maybe I just typed the wrong keywords. Anyway, I'm trying to split string. Sometimes it just work fine but most of the times random characters show up. The string comes from serial port. This is my code: `

```
string Input;
Input = ComPort.ReadExisting();
string[] word = Input.Split(' ');
if (word.Length >= 5)
{            
    Air.Text = word[2];
    Pintu2.Text = word[1];
    Pintu1.Text = word[0];
    Jendela1.Text = word[3];
    Jendela2.Text = word[4];
}
else 
{
    Air.Text = "No Data";
    Pintu2.Text = "No Data";
    Pintu1.Text = "No Data";
    Jendela1.Text = "No Data";
    Jendela2.Text = "No Data";
}
```

Below are the screenshots.

[working one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJQ4t.png)

[random characters showed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pUoO.png)

Comment: did you check every input string to make sure that the string is what you're expecting

Comment: yep, I'm using hyper terminal to see if there's any error in the data transmitted from the serial port but the data looks fine.

Comment: Log it to a file or to the Console each time to be sure!

Comment: I think you should give the working input string and wrong input string.

Comment: The MSDN documentation states: "Note that this method can leave trailing lead bytes in the internal buffer, which makes the BytesToRead value greater than zero." Not sure if that could have anything to do with your problem. One thing you could try is use the Read method and append the input data to a temp buffer until >= 5 "substrings" are collected, then process the data.

Comment: Do you look the same data at the same time? Does the data in plain ASCII or use some encoding? Do you know the expected data when it is incorrectly displayed?

Comment: okay thanks guys. I just tried to log the input string into a file. The data looks like this "Locked Locked 0.00 Open Open Selesai Sele???Locked Locked 0.00 Open Open Se?" when it should only show "Locked Locked 0.00 Open Open Selesai Selesai" everytime I read the comport. Other showed up like this "z????Open Selesai Selesai LockYb??????0.00 Open Open Selesai Selesai Unlocked Un".

Comment: I looks like one of the serial port setting is not the same on the device as in your code.  Normally you should make the settings 8 bit, one stop, no parity.  Also disable hardware and software controls.  I would also use asynchronous read.

Comment: Asynchronous is no handshaking right? And yes I checked the serial configuration and match it. These are the setting from the device and my program. [link](http://i.imgur.com/djhfULU.png) [link](http://i.imgur.com/QTBYA9v.png)